# Thinkpad 370 max brightness reduced after Windows update

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, lcd, brightness, backlight

An automatic Windows update caused by LCD backlight to no longer output its full brightness, even when set to 100%. Basically, what used to be 70% is now 100%. This is a very frustrating problem to solve because every guide online basically just says "well gee, did you try changing the brightness?"

Things I have tried:

- Installed Windows' recommended Intel 620 driver
- Installed Lenovo Vantage's recommended Intel 620 driver
- Installed the latest Intel 620 driver directly from Intel's site
- Ensured the power plan is set to "Maximum Performance" with adaptive brightness turned OFF
- Turned off adaptive brightness in the Windows settings
- Turned ON adaptive brightness in the Windows settings (it doesn't even do anything, I can set the brightness to the minimum level, enable adaptive brightness, and it won't ever change)
- Turned off any settings related to adaptive brightness throughout Windows, Lenovo Vantage, and the Intel Graphics Command Center
- Checked the BIOS for any relevant settings to no avail (all power saving settings are disabled here too)

When I boot up and the Lenovo logo appears, it displays in the crappy 70% brightness as seen in the OS, which would lead me to believe this is some kind of hardware issue. But, for literally a split second before the OS loads, the screen switches to the actual 100% brightness I know and love before switching back. No joke, this happens for like 200ms, but it shows me that the screen is still technically capable of outputting the proper brightness.

The only other explanation I can think of is that I switched my 8gb RAM module to a 16gb one the other day. But I have no idea why this would affect the brightness of the display, especially when plugged in.

Are there any other suggestions to try? My laptop is still under warranty so I'll probably open a support ticket if I can't solve this soon.

EDIT: I took a video of the boot logo, you can clearly see the screen momentarily display at full brightness immediately before the Lenovo logo disappears: https://youtu.be/E5yzF09pC1M

Comment: Try is a workaround. In the Cortana search menu, type in Windows Mobility Center. Open that program, and you'll find a brightness control slider in the top left. It may not play nice with Lenovo's software and you'll see an error popup. Just close it. No harm has been done. Or https://support.lenovo.com/pa/en/solutions/ht500157

Comment: @Alex_Krug Thanks so much for the reply! I just tried this and unfortunately it's set to 100% there as well. The values from this slider seem to correspond exactly to the ones in the action center, and the ones set by the brightness keys on the keyboard. I didn't get any errors either.

Comment: Do you think rolling back the BIOS might be a solution? The screen being dim even while the system boots makes me wonder if this is unrelated to Windows after all.

Comment: If the maximum brightness is set in the BIOS and the "adaptive brightness" mode is turned off in the BIOS, then something must be excluded. I think that BIOS has nothing to do with it. Try booting from any Linux live-CD (for example, https://xubuntu.org/download/) and changing the brightness of the screen. Bootable media (USB-flash, USB-HDD) is very easy to make with Ventoy https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.htm.

Comment: Open Terminal

`$ xrandr`

This command will show the connected displays. 
Try commands

`$ xrandr --output DVI-1 --brightness 0.7`

or

`$ xrandr --output DVI-1 --brightness 1.0`

where replace `DVI-1` with your own video-output name.
If the typed commands change the brightness as you need, the problem is in the OS.